# Inequality involving $p-$variation and $\sup$ norms.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, skorohod-space, p-variation

Let's call $\mathcal D(\Bbb R_{\ge0},\Bbb R^d)$ the Skohrokod space, i.e. the space of the functions $f:\Bbb R_{\ge0}\to\Bbb R^d$ continous on the right which admit limit on the left.

Let's fix $y,l\in \mathcal D(\Bbb R_{\ge0},\Bbb R^d)$ s.t. $y_0\ge l_0$ (when we write inequalities we mean them componentwise).

Then it is well known (Skohrokod problem) that there exist $x,k\in \mathcal D(\Bbb R_{\ge0},\Bbb R^d)$ which solve the following
\begin{align*}
&\bullet \;\;\; x_t=y_t+k_t\ge l_t\;\;\;\forall t\ge0\\
&\bullet\;\;\; k_0=0 \;\;\mbox{, the components of}\;\; k=(k^{(1)},\dots,k^{(d)}),\;\;k^{(i)}\;\;\\
&\mbox{are nondecreasing functions, s.t.}\\
&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\int_0^t(x_s^{(i)}-l_s^{(i)})\,dk_s^{(i)}=0\;\;\;\;\forall t\ge0,\;\; i=1,\dots,d
\end{align*}

It can be proven that $k_t=\sup_{s\le t}(y_s-l_s)^{-}\;$.

One last thing: fixed $p\ge1$, we define the $p-$variation norm of $f\in \mathcal D(\Bbb R_{\ge0},\Bbb R^d)$ as
$$
\bar V_p(f)_T:=|f_0|+\left[\sup_{\pi}\sum_{j=1}^n|f_{t_{j}}-f_{t_{j-1}}|^p\right]^{1/p}
$$

where $\pi=\{0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=T\}$ runs through all the partitions of the interval $[0,T]$.

Ok, here comes my problem: I have to prove the following inequality

> $$ \bar V_p(k)_T\le d\sup_{s\le T}|y_s|+d\sup_{s\le T}|l_s|\;\;. $$

Here's my try:

\begin{align*}
\bar V_p(k)_T
=&\sup_{\pi}\left[\sum_{j=1}^n|k_{t_j}-k_{j-1}|^p\right]^{1/p}+\underbrace{|k_0|}_{=0}\\
\le&\sup_{\pi}\sum_{j=1}^n\left|k_{t_j}-k_{t_{j-1}}\right|\\
=&\sup_{\pi}\sum_{j=1}^n\left[\sum_{i=1}^d(k_{t_j}^{(i)}-k_{t_{j-1}}^{(i)})^2\right]^{1/2}\\
\le&\sup_{\pi}\sum_{j=1}^n\left[\sum_{i=1}^d(k_{t_j}^{(i)}-k_{t_{j-1}}^{(i)})\right]\\
=&\sum_{i=1}^d\left[\sup_{\pi}(k_{t_1}^{(i)}-k_{t_0}^{(i)}+k_{t_2}^{(i)}-k_{t_1}^{(i)}+\cdots+k_{t_n}^{(i)}-k_{t_{n-1}}^{(i)})\right]\\
=&\sum_{i=1}^d1\cdot k_T^{(i)}\\
\mbox{(Cauchy-Schwarz)}\;\;\;\le&\left(\sum_{i=1}^d1^2\right)^{1/2}\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^d(k_T^{(i)})^2\right)^{1/2}\\
=&d^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^d(\sup_{s\le T}(y_s^{(i)}-l_s^{(i)})^{-})^2\right)^{1/2}\\
\le&d\left(\sum_{i=1}^d(\sup_{s\le T}|y_s^{(i)}-l_s^{(i)}|)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
\le&d\left(\sum_{i=1}^d(\sup_{s\le T}|y_s^{(i)}|+\sup_{s\le T}|l_s^{(i)}|)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
\mbox{(Minkowsky)}\;\;\le&d\left(\sum_{i=1}^d(\sup_{s\le T}|y_s^{(i)}|)^2\right)^{1/2}+d\left(\sum_{i=1}^d(\sup_{s\le T}|l_s^{(i)}|)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
%=&d\left|\sup_{s\le T}|y_s|\right|+d\left|\sup_{s\le T}|l_s|\right|
\end{align*}
thus in every sum, the $\sup$ is taken for every summand; instead, in the original inequality, the $\sup$ is taken for the norm of the vector, which gives a stronger inequality than the one written above, since I guess that

$$
\sup_{s\le T}|y_s|=\sup_{s\le T}\left(\sum_{i=1}^d(y_s^{(i)})^2\right)^{1/2}\;\;.
$$
I don't think the authors of the paper wrote

$$
\sup_{s\le T}|y_s|
$$
wanting to meaning exactly
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^d(\sup_{s\le T}|y_s^{(i)}|)^2\right)^{1/2}\;\;.
$$

Comment: I see that you have created ([tag:p-variation]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/p-variation/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. (This is probably not a problem here, since the tag name seems to be descriptive enough.) Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: many thanks. I've just created the relative tag-wiki, I hope it fits good!